# ZPL - Zebra Concatenate 2 values

Tags: zebra-printers, zpl, zpl-ii

I would like to concatenate 2 values in the Zebra Programming Language (ZPL)
Var FN3 contains: 123456

This line currently prints the value 123456

```
^FO260,90^A0N,70,50^FN3^FS
```

^FO: field orientation, with coordinates.
^AON: font type and size
^FN3: variable
^FS: field stop

I tried this:

```
^FO260,90^A0N,70,50^FDP^FN3^FS
```

So we want to have printed: P123456

I cannot find any concatenate function or how to do this in the label.
Any tips or tricks or functions I do not know about?

Comment: What was the result of your test?

Answer (score 0):

The usual way to achieve that result is to use `^FT` rather than `^FO`, for example:

```
^FT260,160^A0N,70,50^FDP^FS^FT^A0N,70,50^FN3^FS
```

Note the second `^FT` with empty parameters.  That indicates to continue formatting the text where the last `^FT` left off.

Unfortunately, using `^FT` means you have to change your coordinates, specifically, your `y` values.  `^FO` positions from the upper left corner.  `^FT` positions from the baseline of the text.